how to check if a string is a number with a built-in Library?
I tried using the isdigit function but it only works for chars. I know I can write a function that'll check every char in a string but is there an already built-in way in c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (isdigit(argv[1]) != 1)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
        return 1;
    }
}


You can loop through each char in the string, checking each one with isdigit.

If your program returns non-zero from main, it should have printed an error message.  If you are going to print a usage statement to stdout, the program should return 0.  If you are going to return non-zero, the program should print an error message to stderr.  Although unfortunately common,  printing a usage statement to stdout and returning non-zero is not best practice.

Could use a regex.

Don't be surprised if you don't understand the answers. They use pointers, which you will only learn about in week 4 of CS50. The assignment you are asking about is from week 2 of CS50.

isdigit(argv[1]) != 1? Do not compare against 1.  Per 7.4.1 Character classification functions, paragraph 1 of the (draft) C11 standard: "The functions in this subclause return nonzero (true) if and only if the value of the argument c conforms to that in the description of the function."

You cannot use isdigit() to way you do in the question: its argument must be a single character (all values of type unsigned char) or the special negative value EOF. Passing a string has undefined behavior.
Your question has many possible answers, depending on what you mean by if a string is a number:

To check if a string pointed to by a pointer s is composed of digits only using strspn defined in <string.h>:
if (*s && s[strspn(s, "0123456789")] == '\0') {
    // s is not empty and contains only digits
}


same test using sscanf defined in `<stdio.h>:
int n = 0;
sscanf(s, "%*[0-9]%n, &n);
if (n > 0 && s[n] == '\0') {
    // s is not empty and contains only digits
}


same test using isdigit defined in `<ctype.h> in a loop:
const char *p = s;
while (isdigit((unsigned char)*p))
    p++;
if (p > s && *p == '\0') {
    // s is not empty and contains only digits
}


same test, using strtol defined in <stdlib.h>. Performs the conversion and accepts optional leading whitespace and an optional sign, may set errno in case of overflow (errno is defined in <errno.h>):
char *p;
long value;
errno = 0;
value = strtol(s, &p, 10);
if (p != s && *p == '\0') {
    // s contains the decimal representation of an integer
    if (errno) {
        // value is too large for type `long`
    }
}



Here is an alternative using no library function correctly:
#include <cs50.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum key_result {
   KEY_OK,          // string is a valid integer
   KEY_TOO_LARGE,   // value is outside the range of type `int`
   KEY_EMPTY,       // string is empty
   KEY_NOT_NUMBER,  // string does not contain only digits
};

/* parse the argument as a key, store value into `*dest` */
enum key_result get_key(const char *s, int *dest) {
    enum key_result res;
    int value;

    // string must not be empty
    if (*s == '\0')
        return KEY_EMPTY;

    value = 0;
    res = KEY_OK;
    // consume digits
    while (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9') {
        int digit = *s++ - '0';
        if ((value > INT_MAX / 10)
        ||  (value == INT_MAX / 10 && digit > INT_MAX % 10)) {
            value = INT_MAX;
            res = KEY_TOO_LARGE;
        } else {
            value = value * 10 + digit;
        }
    }
    if (*s != '\0')
        return KEY_NOT_NUMBER;

    *dest = value;
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int key = 0;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 2;
    }
    switch (get_key(argv[1], &key)) {
      case KEY_OK:
        printf("caesar: key is %d\n", key);
        break;
      case KEY_TOO_LARGE:
        fprintf(stderr, "caesar: key value is too large: '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
      default:
        fprintf(stderr, "caesar: key must be a number\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //...
}


strtol(s, &p, 10) side effect: may set errno.

@chux-ReinstateMonica: converting the number and all that jazz is another question :)

There's many ways to do that, with or without library functions.
One of the most flexible methods would be to use strtol (family), because that one also performs the conversion from string to integer. Example:
#include <stdlib.h>

bool isnumber (const char* str, int* result)
{
  char* endptr = NULL;
  *result = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
  return endptr != str;
}

// usage example:
int n;

if(isnumber("12345", &n))
{
  printf("%d is a number.\n", n);
}


isnumber("12345xyz", &n) also returns true.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Yes on purpose. If the initial part is a valid number then why not allow that?

(If you don't want that, compare endptr against the result from a strlen() call)

"why not allow that?" --> OP'd code seems to want only digits in the entire argv[1], yet you are correct as maybe OP does not care about trailing non-digits.  A simple alternative to "compare endptr against the result from a strlen() call)" is *endptr == '\0'.
